# python sqlite select where cell_string is in user-defined large_string

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, select, sql-like

the idea is to get all cells where string in cell is sub-string of user-provided LARGE string.

is it possible to do with SELECT?

TABLE title_table

COLUMN title

VALUE = 'matrix'

**PASSED** REQUEST

```
"SELECT * FROM title_table WHERE title in (?)", ('matrix',)
```

return correct tuple, but I want to find any matches:

**DESIRED** REQUEST fails

```
"SELECT * FROM title_table WHERE title in (?)", ('matrix has you',)
```

=================

quite simple to do in python, but how to in SQLITE

```
cell_str = 'ABC'
user_feed_str = 'stribngABCqwert'
if cell_str in user_feed_str:
    print("exists")
```

thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: are you looking for `... WHERE title like '%matrix%'`? 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Comment: @Gregor Sturm
fixed with 
'   "SELECT * FROM title_table WHERE (?) LIKE '%'||title||'%' ", ('matrix has you',)   '